# does RemoveFromVisualTree sets all child controls to null?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

does `FrameWorkElement.RemoveFromVisualTree()` remove all child controls of the parent or sets them to null?

for example
is there a difference between

```
var s = (LayoutGroup)sender;
 foreach (var child in s.Children)
    {
       child = null;
    }
 s.RemoveFromVisualTree();
```

and

```
var s = (LayoutGroup)sender;
 s.RemoveFromVisualTree();
```

Comment: It removes the children from the visual tree also (obviously), but doesn't set them to null - they will be garbage collected eventually provided there are no stray references to them.

Comment: @slugster but can i loop thourgh them and set them to null before i call RemoveFromVisualTree()?

Comment: @slugster please check my edit, i've added some code

Comment: @user1590636 Are we actually talking about this method on Visual? [Visual.RemoveVisualChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.removevisualchild.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RemoveVisualChild removes the Parent Child relationship between the two visuals. The same as setting both references to null. This as @slugster mentioned does not trigger GC on the Visuals.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.removevisualchild.aspx

I think you also may be conflating the Visual Tree and Logical Tree in WPF.

The visual tree describes the structure of visual objects as they relate to the control, each of which is based on `System.Windows.Media.Visual`. When you change the appearance of a control buy adding or overriding a Template you are working with the visual tree.

As opposed to the Logical tree which keeps track of object relationships, resources and can contain objects of any type.

More info here: [Trees in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx)